# generic IEqualityComparer using reflection and attributes to mark what i want to compare

Tags: c#

The Intersect should have yielded 0 records because firstname and lastname do not macth. 
 Where did I go wrong....? I suspect is in the equals implementation.

## Thankyou all the problem is solved (  special thanks to Lasse V. Karlsen right on the money with the gethashcode ): Equals plus the hashcode mistake fixed the problem.

## Test Code

```
    var test1 = new ClassA { employeeid = 1, firstName = "a", lastname = "a" };
    var test2 = new ClassA { employeeid = 1, firstName = "a", lastname = "b" };
    IList<ClassA> listA = new List<ClassA>();
    listA.Add(test1);

    IList<ClassA> listB = new List<ClassA>();

    listB.Add(test2);

    //Actual Code
    var Reflection = new ReflectionHelper();
    var ListClassA = Reflection.GetPropertyNames<ClassA>();
    var results = listA.Intersect(listB, new Compare<ClassA>(ListClassA)).ToList();
```

## My comparer

```
 public class KeyComparerAttribute : Attribute{}
 public class Compare<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
        {

            IList<string> keyProperties = new List<string>(); 
            public Compare(IList<string> keyProperties)
            {
                this.keyProperties = keyProperties; 
            }


            public  bool Equals(T x, T y)
            {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var reflection = new ReflectionHelper();
                foreach (var propName in keyProperties)
                {
                    string val1 = reflection.GetPropertyValue<T>(propName, x);
                    string val2 = reflection.GetPropertyValue<T>(propName, y);
                    if (!val1.Equals(val2))
                    {
                      return false; 
                    }
                }
                //if never false then it must be true....
                return true;
            }        
            public  int GetHashCode(T obj)
            {
                int hash = 17;
                foreach (var propInfo in keyProperties)
                {
                    var myValue = reflection.GetPropertyValue(propName:propInfo, src: obj);
                     hash = hash * 23 + myValue.GetHashCode();
                }
                return hash;
            }


        }
```

## My helper classes just for reference

```
public class ReflectionHelper 
        {
            public IList<string> GetPropertyNames<T>() 
            {
                IList<string> propertyNames = new List<string>(); 
                var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(
                    BindingFlags.Public |
                    BindingFlags.Static |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Default |
                    BindingFlags.Instance).ToList().
                    Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(KeyComparerAttribute)));
                // write property names
                if (propertyInfos.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                    {
                       propertyNames.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
                    }
                }
                return propertyNames;
            }
            public string GetPropertyValue<T>(string propName, T src)
            {
                return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null).ToString();
            }
    }
```

## Class A

```
 public class ClassA
    {

        public int employeeid { get; set; }
        [KeyComparer]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        [KeyComparer]
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: In any case, even if the comparer did work, he would be putting the same two instances in both lists, I don't understand what he's testing here.

Comment: Additionally he has implemented a very incorrect GetHashCode for his scenario, it should use the same properties as the comparer does to calculate the hashcode.

Comment: They should be the same properties for the hashcode actually.

Comment: The list lastname property value is b in one list and the other is a. Hence, intersect should return 0.

Comment: @hidden: You're currently calling `GetHashCode()` on the `PropertyInfo` for the properties, not the *values* of the properties...

Comment: According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
and I am doing the same thing but with reflection.
 
if (b1.Height == b2.Height & b1.Length == b2.Length
                            & b1.Width == b2.Width)
        {
            return true;
        }

Comment: The implementation from gethashcode is straight from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode u r saying that is wrong? Should I have gotten the value on the line  typeof(T).GetProperty(propInfo)

Comment: I'm saying your implementation is wrong. You read the propertyinfo objects, which will always be the same. It should be based on the values of those properties.

Comment: K i see that correcting that now.

Comment: @hidden Can you please paste your updated code? I'm very curious to see how it 'fixes' the problem. I'll even run it in VS just to make sure :). Unless there's a bug in the .NET framework, the behavior of returning 2 items as a result of your intersect, given your input, is the correct one. edit: nevermind, you changed it so that listA is only test1 and listB is test2. That would indeed yield 0 as intersection but it's different to the original problem :).

Comment: Yes i updated the question to reflect the final solution.

Comment: Please do not update your question to include answers. If you answered your own question, post your solution as an answer and accept it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

According to my high school math:

```
SetA = {test1, test2}
SetB = {test1, test2}
SetA = SetB (conceptually speaking) => SetA (intersect) SetB = SetA
```

Or what did you expect to see?

If you change it to

```
SetA = {test1}
SetB = {test2}
```

You will get `{0}` (empty set).

Regardless, I wouldn't recommend this for a prod code. At the very least, cache the property infos when you've already inspected a class in your ReflectionHelper.

This code will run (comparatively) very slowly if you have lots of comparison (as you implicated in your reasoning for implementing this). Whilst I very much like avoiding writing boiler plate codes, sometimes it's worth writing it due to performance/maintainability reasons.

Comment: Thats the point I get result =2. My goal is to get 0 just as your high school math dictates.

Comment: Use except instead of intersect then ;-) var results = listA.Except(listB, new Compare<ClassA>(ListClassA)).ToList();

Comment: Is probably LasseV.Karlsen said about ==. I need to replace any call to == to equals... i think...

Comment: the issue is the math behind intersect. If you replace == with .equals, it won't make any difference. For your case, string.equals is the same as == due to interning so you got lucky there (though you should replace it with .equals anyway to make sure it works with complex types too).

Comment: Intersect means Given a subset a{1 2 3} intersect b{1} resulting set is c{1} or am i crazy.Also I already did the concrete implementation and this works but I am failing at the generic one.

Comment: Nope, you are correct. Your subset is a{1 2} and b{1 2}. Intersect of 'a' and 'b' = c {1 2}